# App is unsafe blocked by google play protect

Tags: android-studio

I made an simple qr code application in android studio which opens scanned result in web browser but after signing with number of keystore files I am getting same error from google play protect after installing the app.(may be it's the issue of using https or web browser?) How to solve this ?

Getting error of unsafe app from google play protect after installing app